# Excel, make sum across pages based on cell color

Tags: excel

Maybe this is a trivial question but just in case anyone encountered the same problem.

I have a excel workbook with several sheets and in each sheet, I want to mark some cells with a particular color (green) and have them sum all together (from all sheets).

This is a spent personal report and each sheet contains comments, so I don't have precise locations for sub-totals.

One solution could be sheet1:A20 + sheet2:B34 ... and so on (manually)

Other it cross my mind will be for each cell that I want as sub-total to colorize in green and make a VBA to sum all across all sheets by color?

Appreciate ideas,

Comment: You can't sum by a colour. Your manual solution is likely the best solution. If that's too cumbersome, you'll need to look into VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to sum up all values in a specific Range (B2-B4 in my case - but that could be expanded to other ranges, of course):

```
Dim sumYellowCells As Integer
Dim sumGreenCells As Integer

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B4")
    If cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen Then
        sumGreenCells = sumGreenCells + cell.Value
    End If

    If cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
        sumYellowCells = sumYellowCells + cell.Value
    End If
Next
Debug.Print sumGreenCells & "-" & sumYellowCells
```